# Retrieve Enumerations in Polarion?

Tags: polarion

Is there any way to retrieve all Options for a Enumeration (including description) in Polarion?

I have tried multiple things:

1. Searching the enum via Dataservice

```
$trackerService.getDataService().getEnumerationObjectFactories().get("@WorkItems").getEnumeration("processes-enum.xml", $contextId).getAllOptions().get(0)
```

this does return an EnumOption, but its from the "wrong side". If i use .getName() or getId() it returns the name and Id of a Workitem (so getAllOptions means I get all possible Applications for an Enumeration but not the content of the actual Enumeration file.

2. Using custom Fields

```
#set($projectId = $page.getReference().projectId())
#set($trackerProject = $trackerService.getTrackerProject($projectId))
$trackerProject.getWorkItem("myWorkitem").getCustomField("myEnum").getProperty("description")
```

This correctly gets the description for the EnumOption for myWorkitem for myEnum. This is already good, but now I can only access EnumOptions descriptions that are "used" in a Workitem.

3. CustomFieldsService

```
#set($customFieldsService = $trackerService.getDataService().getCustomFieldsService())
$customFieldsService.getCustomField("myEnum", "WorkItem", $contextId)
```

This correctly returns an instance of a CustomField, but this doesnt really help me, since I can't search for all possible Options for this Custom Field

Is there something I am missing? Is there a way to access the description of EnumOptions for an Enum in Polarion?

Comment: Struggling here as well: I thought I had a breakthrough yesterday, when I learned that pageParameters of type enum can be accessed with ```singleValue()```, but that doesn't work for workitems in wiki code unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Using `.getClass().getName()` on the output of `getCustomField(key)`, I learned that it actually is an `AbstractTypedList` which has a [get(int) method](https://testdrive.polarion.com/polarion/sdk/doc/javadoc/com/polarion/platform/persistence/spi/AbstractTypedList.html#get(int)).

Retrieving the first item of the field suddenly lets you call the `id` property:

```
$workitem.getCustomField("release").get(0).id
```